# Port 53 on a Windows 7 machine is inaccessible from LAN

Tags: home-networking, ports, netstat

Installed a nice dns filter (Acrylic) on my server running Win7. Wanted all machines on the LAN to use it for name resolution. On the server NETSTAT shows Acrylic is listening on  DNS port:

```
UDP    0.0.0.0:53             *:*
  [AcrylicService.exe]
```

and browser on the server goes through the Acrylic.
However no other computer on the LAN can see or use this. port scanner does not even show this port open on the server. Other ports (e.g. 80 and 21) are visible, but not 53!

So, the questions is,
Why this port is not visible from the outside? Is it the app (Acrylic Service) or something with Windows blocking it even with the Firewall off?

Comment: `netstat -baton | find /I ":53 " ` may be DNS client or dns server use port? `Wmic service where (Name like "%dns%") get caption, name, startmode, state, ProcessId` Use telnet client or scan port tools.

Comment: is your firewall enabled on the server, and have you created an allow rule for UDP53 in both directions?

Comment: FWall is disabled completely... First thing I did..

Comment: netstat -baton | find /I ":53 " - confirms that the AcrylicService.exe process own it.. nothing else.